# how to display text and image in a column of a gridview in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

From a database if there is a simple text then text should display in a gridview, if in table the text is the name of image file then the image should display

Example

```
id           text
----         -------
1            hello
2            hi
3            imagename.jpg
```

Now i want to display hello and hi in column[0] of gridview, also image(imagename.jpg) in the same column i.e column[0]...
pls help

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20782/Displaying-Images-from-a-Database-in-a-GridView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015209/list-with-images-from-code-behind-asp-net-c-to-image-overview-in-aspx/14017514#14017514

Comment: @GopeshSharma...ya i know this...but in this link only the images is there...i wan both text and image in one column

Comment: If you want them both in one column create an ItemTemplate, a simple Google search will bring back more than enough results if you've never done it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         string img = ((Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image1")).ImageUrl;
         string []ext=img.Split('.');
         if (ext.Length == 1)
         {
             ((Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image1")).Visible = false;
         }
         else
         {
             ((Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image1")).Visible = true;
         }
      }
     BindGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have column of type `DataGridViewImageColumn` and giving text to the image.

```
DataGridViewImageColumn column = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
column.HeaderText = "Image Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdImages" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>

      <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="URL" NullDisplayText="Text when no image."/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        grdImages.DataSource = yourDataSource;
        grdImages.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: by this code i will get name in one column and images in other column, but i dont want that.... If in table if there is simple text the in a grid column text should display but if it is filename then image should display

Comment: @vaishali check my updated answer. use NullDisplayText property for displaying text when no image url.